# problems with mysql userdefined function charset

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a mysql function doing manipulation on strings. each char is changed by adding a number to its ascii value (making it another char) and then concating it to a string again
doing it on php - all works fine, and each char has a value of less than 256
doing it on the mysql - each char gets a value of more than 50000
field is utf-8

any ideas ?

mysql code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS wizner_denc;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION wizner_denc(code TEXT,ciper TEXT)
  RETURNS TEXT CHARSET utf8 READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE enc_str TEXT;
  DECLARE kk INT;
  DECLARE kmax INT;
  DECLARE cc TEXT;
  DECLARE stp TEXT;
  DECLARE cmax INT;
  DECLARE code_idx INT;

  SET enc_str=CHARSET(ciper);
  SET code_idx = 1;
  SET kk = 1;
  SET kmax=LENGTH(ciper);
  SET cmax=LENGTH(code);

  WHILE (kk < kmax) DO
    SET cc=ORD(SUBSTRING(ciper,kk,1));
    SET stp = SUBSTRING(code, code_idx, 1);
    SET cc=cc-stp;
    IF  cc <= 0 THEN
        SET cc=250+cc;
    END  IF;
    SET enc_str=CONCAT(enc_str,'...cc=',cc,'...stp=',stp,'|||');
    SET enc_str=CONCAT(enc_str,CHAR(cc));
    SET code_idx=code_idx+1;
    IF code_idx >= cmax THEN
        SET code_idx=1;
    END IF;
    SET kk = kk + 1;

  END WHILE;
  RETURN enc_str;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
SET NAMES utf8;
SELECT wizner_denc('232323',CONVERT(address  USING utf8)),address FROM `demo_clients_tbl` WHERE 1
```

results:

```
utf8...cc=55697...stp=2|||ّ...cc=55721...stp=3|||٩...cc=55704...stp=2|||٘...cc=55720...stp=3|||٨...cc=248...stp=2|||...cc=248...stp=2|||...cc=247...stp=3|||
```

where on the php I see the numbers:

```
... cc-217 stp=2 
... cc-147 stp=3 
... cc-217 stp=2 
... cc-172 stp=3 
... cc-217 stp=2 
... cc-154 stp=3 
... cc-217 stp=2 
... cc-171 stp=3
```

for the same row on DB

Comment: That _"adding a number to its __ascii__ value"_ and _"field is __utf-8__"_ don't mix well should be obvious. Btw, looks like you are trying to implement your own form of (very basic) "encryption" ... you should use one of the already implemented encryption functions instead.

Comment: you are right, i am creating my own encryption. moving to already implemented function is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. 
In mysql the non-English letters are 2 bytes which comes together (i.e. 55697) while in php it come byte after byte. 
So i've converted the mysql reply into 2 numbers and made the manipulation as in php.
 Note that for English letters, there is no need for that (reply will be smaller than 256)